# How do I set the date of Kalendae to 17 years in the past?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae which is a datepicker based on JS.

I was wondering if it's possible to set the Kalendae current month /day to 17 years ago + blackout the future from that point on.

My current Kalendae is made like this:

```
(:class => "auto-kal", "data-kal" => "format:'DD/MM/YYYY',weekStart:1")
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be what you are looking for:

```
var my_date = moment().subtract('years', 17); // Calculate calendar date = current - 17 years
new Kalendae(document.body, {
    format: 'D/M/YYYY', // Set calendar date format
    selected: my_date.format('D/M/YYYY'), // Set calendar date with same format as calendar expects it
    direction: 'past', 
    blackout: function (date) {
        return date > my_date; // Blackout calendar days that are greater than my_date
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6u2C/)

The solution uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, since I'm using Rails and not pure jQuery is it possible to add the blackout on Window Load? This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/VWOU/X3Zu9/ the my_date part get's mingled up to just random numbers when trying to concatenate it with blackout

Comment: @VWOU Please note that I didn't use jQuery on my fiddle and the jsfiddle website executes the code in the onLoad event. By mistake I added jQuery to the list of `Frameworks & Extensions` but here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6u2C/1/) with no jQuery and it still works. Also note that I used three external resources: the calendar library JS, the calendar CSS and the moment library JS. They are in the fiddle on the left side under `External Resources`.

Comment: Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6u2C/2/) to include the calendar in a different element (an ID and not a class) than the the `<body>`. When doing it just put the code inside your onLoad function (jsfiddle does that for you but you need to do so yourself in your page) and don't forget to include the three following tags: `<script src="http://chipersoft.com/Kalendae/build/kalendae.standalone.min.js" type="text/javascript">`, `<link href="http://chipersoft.com/Kalendae/build/kalendae.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` and `http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js`.